# Timing sequence in terms of percentages

Tags: java, image, time, timer

I need help from you guys. I got struck at the timing intervals. I am having 8 images total. These images need to run at time intervals at percentage way.
**Image 1** to be displayed on the screen= 0% of the overall time.**Image 2** = 20% of the overall time (total 20%) **Image 3** = 20% of the overall time (total 40%) **Image 4** = 60% of the overall time (total 60%) **Image 5** = 80% of the overall time (total 80%)  **Image 6** = 90% of the overall time (total 90%) **Image 7** = 95% of the overall time (total 95%)  **Image 8** = 100% of the overall time (total 100%).

In the below code i have written like this total time/ 8 images i.e; for example if i choose 2 minutes and it is converted into milliseconds and then it is 120000/8 = 15000 milliseconds that means the images will run for every 15 seconds by the end total images runs but now i need to run these images in mentioned above percentage way. If images run in percentage the 1st image should display at 0% of 120seconds. 2nd image should display at 20% of 120seconds i.e; 24 seconds. 3rd image should display at 40% of 120seconds i.e; 48 seconds.4th image should display at 60% of 120seconds i.e; 72 seconds. 5th image should display at 80% of 120seconds i.e; 96 seconds. 6th image should display at 90% of 120seconds i.e; 108 seconds. 7th image should display at 95% of 120seconds i.e; 114 seconds. 8th image should display at 100% of 120seconds i.e; 120 seconds.

```
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat testhrFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
        SimpleDateFormat testminFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
        String formattedDate = testhrFormat.format(c.getTime());
        int minDate = Integer.parseInt(testminFormat.format(c.getTime()));
        long hrlong = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(Long.parseLong(formattedDate));
        addedmin = hrlong + minDate;
        twwntyhrformat = displayFormat.format(c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        SharedPreferences timegot = getSharedPreferences("CHILDTIME", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String time = timegot.getString("savedwakeuptime", "");
        try {
            Date date = parseFormat.parse(time);
            String gottime = displayFormat.format(date);
            String[] timedivided = gottime.split(":");
            String gothr = timedivided[0];
            long gotlong = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(Long.parseLong(gothr));
            String gotmin = timedivided[1];
            int gotintmin = Integer.parseInt(gotmin);
            addgottime = gotlong + gotintmin;
            long subtime = addgottime - addedmin;
            String submilli = String.valueOf(subtime);
            long submillitimeunit = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(Long.parseLong(submilli));
            flippingtime = (int) (submillitimeunit / 8);
            handler = new Handler();
            run = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String number = String.valueOf(fliper.getDisplayedChild());
                    if (number.equals("7")) {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(run);
                    } else {
                        fliper.showNext();
                        handler.postDelayed(run, flippingtime);
                    }
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(run, flippingtime);
            Log.d("ConvertMilli--wakeup", String.valueOf(submillitimeunit) + " " + String.valueOf(subtime) + " " + flippingtime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which framework do you use to display the images?

Comment: I dont know what is a framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
int totalTime = ....;
List<Integer> intervals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intervals.add(0); // 0%
intervals.add((int)(totalTime * 0.20f)); // 20%
intervals.add((int)(totalTime * 0.40f)); // 40%
intervals.add((int)(totalTime * 0.60f)); // 60%
intervals.add((int)(totalTime * 0.80f)); // 80%;
intervals.add((int)(totalTime * 0.90f)); // 90%
intervals.add((int)(totalTime * 0.95f)); // 95%
intervals.add(totalTime); // 100%

Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        fliper.showNext(); 
    }
};

for(int interval:intervals){
    handler.postDelayed(run, interval);
}
```

Comment: Bro, it's not working every image is taking 2 minutes to move next image.

Comment: @SampleTesting oh, I've used `/` instead of `*`, I've edited my answer to fix that. Give it a try now.

Comment: now images are not moving when i changed from " / " to " * "

Comment: @SampleTesting make sure you've calculated the `totalTime` correctly.

Comment: Actually this is my actual code flippingtime = (int) (submillitimeunit / 8); in this submillitimeunit is the total time and 8 is the total images. When i run this code the images running and moving to next image if i give 2 minutes over there it is 120/8 means every images goes to next image by every 15 seconds but now i need them in mentioned percentage.

Comment: @SampleTesting just replace `totalTime` from my code with `submillitimeunit` and this should work. From what I understand `submillitimeunit` is the total time in milliseconds from which the percentages should be calculated.

Comment: Sample Testing has only 1 reputation, not yet enough to chat so, we need continue in comments. Well coming to the point with your comment i am trying with your code only that is total time.